# MYSQL: search in an additional table with IN(select from

Tags: mysql

How can i add a second SELECT * FROM? To search in an additional table with IN( .. )

**i have (is working):**

```
Select * from Table where
    (b.id_parent in (select product_id from product_keywords where keyword='" . $search . "')) ";
```

**i want to add:**

```
    or (select product_id from product_keywords_NEW where keyword='" . $search . "')
```

Comment: It should be `OR b.id_parent IN (select ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `exists` and correlated subqueries:

```
select *
from mytable t
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from product_keywords pk 
        where pk.keyword = ? and pk.product_id = t.id_parent)
    or exists (
        select 1 
        from product_keywords_new pkn
        where pkn.keyword = ? and pkn.product_id = t.id_parent
    )
```

`exists` performs better than `in` on large datasets.

Note that I also changed your query so the keyword to search for is given as a parameter to the query rather than concatenated in the query string. This is more efficient, and prevents SQL injection.

Depending on your data, it *might* be more efficient to use `union all` and a single `exists` condition rather then `or` and two subquerires:

```
select *
from mytable t
where 
    exists (
        select 1 
        from (
            select product_id, keyword from product_keywords 
            union all 
            select product_id, keyword from product_keywords_new
        ) pk
        where pk.keyword = ? and pk.product_id = t.id_parent
    )
```